# jQuery validation addmethod always return false

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery validation 1.8.2 I added ajax which I check response all correct value is also passing correct but still I am not getting validation. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("#form1").validate({
      rules: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [12,12],
          digits: true,
          checkCivilID: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [8,8],
          digits: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: "Civil for is required!",
          rangelength: "Civil for should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Civil for should be only numbers!"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: "First Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: "Last Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: "Mobile number is required!",
          rangelength: "Mobile number should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Mobile number should be only numbers!"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: "Select User Type !"
      },
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $('label[for="' + element.attr("id") + '"]').text(error.text());
      }
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkCivilID", function (value, element) {
      var response = '';
      $.ajax({
        url: "CivilID.aspx/IsAlreadyAvailable",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: "{'civilID':'" + value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          return data.d == 0 ? true : false;
        }
      });
    }, "CivilID is Already Exists");
});
  </script>
```

I change my addMethod to remote method and now my code is as per below but still it is same :(

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("#form1").validate({
      rules: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [12,12],
          digits: true,
          remote: function () {
            var value = $('#<%=txCivilID.ClientID%>').val();
            var r = {
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              data: JSON.stringify({ civilID: value }),
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "CivilID.aspx/IsAlreadyAvailable",
              //async: false,
              dataFilter: function (data) { return $.parseJSON(data).d }
            };
            return r;
          }
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [8,8],
          digits: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: "Civil for is required!",
          rangelength: "Civil for should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Civil for should be only numbers!",
          remote:"CivilID is Already Exists"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: "First Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: "Last Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: "Mobile number is required!",
          rangelength: "Mobile number should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Mobile number should be only numbers!"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: "Select User Type !"
      },
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $('label[for="' + element.attr("id") + '"]').text(error.text());
      }
    });

    /*jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkCivilID", function (value, element) {
      var response = '';
      $.ajax({
        url: "CivilID.aspx/IsAlreadyAvailable",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: "{'civilID':'" + value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          return data.d == 0 ? true : false;
        }
      });
    }, "CivilID is Already Exists");*/
});

 </script>
```

Comment: What will be the result when `alert(data.data)`?

Comment: Sorry it is data.d and I am getting 0 when it is already exists and 1 when it is not exists

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9jt4A/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny your jsfiddle is giving error

Comment: Why use a custom method for this when you can use `remote` rule?

Comment: jQuery Validate 1.8.2 is really pretty old.  You should be using v1.11.1

Comment: It was nice suggestion and I implement it but still I am facing same issue

Comment: I use remote method still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, as people told me use remote method and I did that but still it was giving same issue. Then I start changing out value of web service. It was first bool then I change to Boolean but still it was same issue and now I make it string and returning value true and false.

Bingo it start working :D