# jQuery Validate remote method not firing success or error callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate username already exists or not using the following script

```
$('#editAccount').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: 'index.php?route=account/edit/validate_username',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    username: function() {
                        return $('#username').val();
                    }
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('test');
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: 'You can\'t leave this empty.'
        },
        lastname: {
            required: 'You can\'t leave this empty.'    
        },
        username: {
            required: 'You can\'t leave this empty.'
        }
    }
});
```

In the above script it is not firing either success or error. The `remote` url returns `{"status":1} json`. What's wrong with the above script?

**Update - 1**

Consider this as my php file

```
$status = check_for_availability($username);
if($status) {
    echo "true";
    //echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => 'Username '.$username.' is still available'));
} else {
    echo "false";
    //echo json_encode(array('status' => 0, 'message' => 'Username '.$username.' is not available. Try with another one.'));
            }
```

Comment: Use `data.Status` to identify the value

Comment: success/error does not return anything

Comment: You'll need to show us the remote PHP function as well as the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: @Sparky I had some problem with firefox it seems its working only on firefox private window. Now getting response as true and false but how can I restrict form submission if user exists and allow form submission if user not exists.

Answer (score -1):

Try to return value true or false in string format. It should return {"status":"true"} and yes @Amit Agrawal is correct you should use data.Status

Refere to this thread.
[jQuery validation addmethod always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324424/jquery-validation-addmethod-always-return-false)

Comment: Same it returns nothing

Comment: Did you make sure that data is posting properly. Did you try to debug it

Comment: try dataType:'json' inside remote

Comment: @Milind data are posting properly am getting response while inspecting but in console(success) it is not working.

Comment: try reponse result with string from php. I mean with double quotes

Comment: are u returning json encoded data or just using echo $result in your action if echoing $result then use dataType:'html'

Comment: @RonitAdhikari json response only

Comment: what is the result for console.log(data)

Comment: @RonitAdhikari thats what am saying `console.log(data)` does not return anything

Comment: then there might be problem in your validate_username action just directly hit the url and echo the result then you will get close to error